# How to solve these equations and find solutions for $W, X, Y, Z$

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I want to solve these four equations and find the solutions for $W, X, Y, Z$

$$\begin{aligned} b.W+g(W-X)Z &=a\\ c.W-d.X+g(W-X)Z &=0\\ e.W+d.X-f.Y &=0\\ s.g(W-X)Z+s.m.b.W-h.Z &=0\end{aligned}$$

And is there any possibility to solve these using matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

From the first two equations,

$$a-bW-cW+dX=0$$

and from the first and fourth,

$$s(a-bW)+smbW-hZ=0.$$

Hence you can express $X$ and $W$ as linear functions of $Z$.

Plugging them in the first equation, you will obtain a quadratic equation in $Z$, that should have two solutions.

You will draw $Y$ from the third equation.

Comment: Thank You for your support